# Alinear círculos con CSS y Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

esto trabajando con css y bootstrap y lo que intento hacer es como lo que se muestra en la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que llevo, pero la verdad ya llevo varios días y no me queda, lo que quiero hacer es que estén al mismo nivel los círculos de arriba y los de abajo tomando como referencia el círculo central y que cuando se visualice en modo responsivo se acople correctamente (No tomen en cuenta el menu que aparece).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Código
>
> HTML

```html
<div class="case-study-content">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="container">
      
              <div class="row">
                <a href="" style="padding-right: 10%"><img class="rounded-circle" src="<?=base_url()?>assets/images/pagina/home/home_1.jpg" alt="" style="border-radius: 50%; width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 2px solid #ddd; padding: 10px;">
                
                <a href="" style="padding-left: 10%"><img class="rounded-circle" src="<?=base_url()?>assets/images/pagina/home/home_1.jpg" alt="" style="border-radius: 50%; width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 2px solid #ddd; padding: 10px;">
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <a href="">
                  <div class="circulo">
                    <h1>ZoHo</h1>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <a href=""><img class="rounded-circle" src="<?=base_url()?>assets/images/pagina/home/home_1.jpg" alt="" style="border-radius: 50%; width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 2px solid #ddd; padding: 10px;">
            
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

> CSS

```css
.circulo {
        border: 3px solid #ddd;
        width: 30rem;
        height: 30rem;
        border-radius: 50%;
        /*background: red;*/
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        text-align: center;
        margin:0px auto;
        padding:3%
      }

      .circulo > h2 {
        font-family: sans-serif;
        color: white;
        font-size: 1.4rem;
        font-weight: bold;
      }


            .container .row {
        /*margin: 20px;*/
        text-align: center;
      }

      .container .row a {
        /*margin: 0 20px;*/
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

Podrias utilizar `flex` que te ayudara a alinear los objetos y que todo sea responsivo.

Solo debes añadir a tu seccion de estilos

```
.col-md-12 .container .row{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.col-md-12 .container .firstRow{
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

y suprimir los `paddings` aplicado a los circulos.

En tu codigo quedaria asi:

```css
.col-md-12 .container .row{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.col-md-12 .container .firstRow{
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
.circulo {
  border: 3px solid #ddd;
  width: 30rem;
  height: 30rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /*background: red;*/
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.circulo > h2 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="case-study-content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row firstRow">
            <a href=""><img class="rounded-circle" src="https://picsum.photos/id/234/300/300.jpg" alt=""
                style="border-radius: 50%; width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 2px solid #ddd; padding: 10px;">
              <a href=""><img class="rounded-circle" src="https://picsum.photos/id/234/300/300.jpg" alt=""
                  style="border-radius: 50%; width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 2px solid #ddd; padding: 10px;">
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <a href="">
              <div class="circulo">
                <h1>ZoHo</h1>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <a href=""><img class="rounded-circle" src="https://picsum.photos/id/234/300/300.jpg" alt=""
                style="border-radius: 50%; width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 2px solid #ddd; padding: 10px;">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Espero que te sirva, saludos.